# MongoDB mongoose Deprecation Warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

While querying the documents by using `collection.find` I started getting following warning in my console

> DeprecationWarning: collection.find option [fields] is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a later version

Why am I seeing this and how do I fix this? (Possible alternatives)

**EDIT: Query Added**

```
Session
        .find({ sessionCode: '18JANMON', completed: false })
        .limit(10)
        .sort({time: 1})
        .select({time: 1, sessionCode: 1});
```

***Mongoose version 5.2.9***

Comment: Did you try to use collection.find(query).limit(1).project({name:1})?

Comment: Hi @DanieleTassone whenever i use find() this warning appears

Comment: Could you post your full query

Comment: the native mongodb driver is something that Mongoose internally use to deal with MongoDB. If Mongoose do not respect some new "rules" then a warning is returned back. With native-driver you will receive this warning if you use "fields option" instead of cursor function for example. Take a look here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6667

Comment: There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6880) is opened... So till it gets resolved you can use mongoose version **5.2.8**

Comment: Let me know if you need help downgrading to 5.2.8 version. `npm install mongoose@5.2.8` should work. The [fix](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/6888) has already been merged to master. So 5.2.10 should have that fix when it is released.

Comment: Thanks @Veeram :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Update:**

5.2.10 is released and available for download [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose).

For more info on the docs you can view page
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations

For more info on the issue and its fix
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6880

**Original Answer:**

Mongoose 5.2.9 version upgraded the native mongodb driver to  3.1.3 in which changes were added to throw warning messages when the deprecated native driver method is called.

[`fields`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html) option is deprecated and is replaced with `projection` option.

You will have to wait for mongoose to make changes at their end to replace the fields option with projection. The fix is scheduled for   5.2.10 release.

For time being you can go back to 5.2.8 which will suppress all deprecation warnings.

```
npm install mongoose@5.2.8
```

For all other deprecated warnings you have to approach them case by case.

You will see other deprecation warnings when you use other collection methods.

```
DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.
DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.
DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
DeprecationWarning: collection.save is deprecated. Use insertOne, insertMany, updateOne, or updateMany instead.
DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
```

All `findOne*` mongoose write methods by default use the [`findAndModify`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) method which is deprecated in mongodb native driver.

Use `mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);` to have mongooose call the appropriate `findOne*` method on the mongodb native driver.

For `remove` and `update` replace those calls with `delete*` and `update*` methods respectively.

For `save` replace those calls with `insert*`/ `update*` methods respectively.

Use `mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);` to have mongooose call the `createIndex` method on the mongodb native driver.

Comment: I'm confused: why did you update the answer with info on how to fix the `ensureIndex` deprecation when this question is about the deprecated `find` option?

Comment: @skerit Thanks - Updated answer. I was trying to cover all the deprecated warnings.

Answer (score 19):

```
mongoose.connect('your db url', {
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
```

or

```
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
mongoose.connect('your db url', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Nah this is a good answer. Warning is gone.

Answer (score 5):

After upgrading to version 5.2.10. Any of the options below can be use

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {

  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true

})
.then(() => console.log('connecting to database successful'))
.catch(err => console.error('could not connect to mongo DB', err));
```

---

or

---

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',{

    useNewUrlParser: true

})
.then(() =>  console.log('connecting to database successful') )
.catch(err =>  console.error('could not connect to mongo DB', err) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `npm install mongoose@5.2.8` and this will help you get back to an earlier version which will not show any deprecation warnings

Comment: Just downgrading the version to avoid warnings? 

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me at April, 2020:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tablename',{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true,useCreateIndex: true },()=>{
    console.log(`connected db`)
});`

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using "mongoose@5.11.15"
you can get rid of the DeprecationWarning by using this,

**Method 1**

```
mongoose.connect("Your DB address", {
useNewUrlParser: true,                       
useUnifiedTopology: true,                 
useCreateIndex: true               // to handle collection.ensureIndex is deprecated
});
```

**Method 2**

```
mongoose.connect("Your DB address", {
useNewUrlParser: true,                       
useUnifiedTopology: true,                 // other deprecation warnings            
});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);     // to handle collection.ensureIndex is deprecated
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use
--no-deprecation
in CLI to ignore the deprecation warnings.

I was getting this warning- (node:108) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
by using --no-deprecation it worked fine

Check documentation here -
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_no_deprecation

Answer (score 1):

When we make connection request to connect mongo db we just have to add one more key value pair into that callback function

```
useCreateIndex:true
```

inside the function

```
mongoose.connect(config.DB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex:true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass following options while data base connection

for e.g.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("uri",{ 
                       "useNewUrlParser": true,
                       "useUnifiedTopology": true, 
                       "useCreateIndex": true 
                       // other deprecations 
                       },(err)=>{
     // connection logging
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useCreateIndex: true,
 useFindAndModify: false,
 useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => {
 console.log("DB connected");
})
.catch((err) => console.log(`DB connection Err`, err));
```

Answer (score 0):

here
`connectionString` is your DB Address

```js
mongoose
  .connect(connectionString, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`server started on port ${port}`);
    })
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Am using mongoose version 6.8.0 and this worked for me**

```
 //connect mongodb 
     mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
     mongoose.connect('url',(err,db) => {

    if(err){
        console.log(`Database not connected :   ${err}`)
    }else{
        console.log('Database connected Successfully')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if depreciation error occurred to you while trying to connect to your mongodb database, if you are storing your connection strings in an environment variables file, like this

```
//database connection string saved to a env variable
DB='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/players'
```

use the actual ip address instead of the common way of defining it:

```
DB='mongodb://localhost/players'
```

Then, when connecting to the database you can use, this code:

```
//requiring the database driver mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connecting to mongodb
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB)
.then(() => console.log('Connected to mongodb Database...'))
.catch((err) => console.error('Unable to connect to MongoDB...', err));
```

This definitely, worked for me..am using locally on my machine so if you are using server based database then your database connnection string will not be the same as mine.