# MongoDB deprecation warnings when using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose version **5.2.13**, the latest I suppose. But when I try executing the **.findOneAndUpdate()** query, Mongo throws a deprecation warning:

> DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use
>   findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.

Is this known behavior that should be fixed in future versions of mongoose? Or should I do something about it? The query I'm running is:

```
output2 = await dbUser.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: args.authorid },
   { $push: { posts: newpost2 } },
);
```

I'm not very comfortable downgrading my packages in case that's a possible suggestion as offered in [MongoDB mongoose collection.find options Deprecation Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916630/mongodb-mongoose-collection-find-options-deprecation-warning/52043442#52043442).

Comment: Why will downgrade your module. Read the warning it says if `findAndModify ` is being used then be assured that its deprecated. Just ignore it if you are not using.

Comment: The deprecation warning doesn't say "if" `findAndModify` is being used and I suppose the warning is thrown by MongoDB only if the offending method is indeed being called. And the downgrade idea was suggested in a similar SO post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916630/mongodb-mongoose-collection-find-options-deprecation-warning/52043442#52043442.

Comment: I will rather try what first answer suggests. Mongodb itself hasn't mentioned anything as such in their find and modify documentation.

Comment: Have you tried setting `mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);` ?

Comment: @Veeram, that works, thanks. I was just hoping there were a more generic solution not involving having to explicitly set arguments on every single instance of mongoose. However, if no other alternative comes to mind, could you please post this as the answer so I could accept and close?

Comment: You're welcome. This is already noted in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918795/2683814). Mongoose 6 version will remove all the flags and call the appropriate  mongo driver methods.

Comment: In that case, would you suggest I mark this question for deletion?

Answer (score 4):

Reference : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

Add Param : **useFindAndModify: false**

Eg Code:

```
    mongoose.connect(
        MONGODB_URL, {
        useFindAndModify: false
      },
      (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`MongoDB connected on port ${MONGODB_PORT}`);
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to avoid this warning you have to add `useFindAndModify: false` to the connection options as mentioned in [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify)

as the following:

> `mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false });`

---

Also, you can upgrade it to ***(v5.12.15)***; which is the latest version; besides using the earlier mentioned *connection option*