# DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, deprecated

I am using mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` but still getting the error,

> DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.

But I am not even using `findAndModify`, why is it converting my query to `findAndModify`?

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: @ShivamPandey Latest which is `5.3.0`

Comment: It just recently released. I would say they should add change log in their releases.

Comment: That warning appears when I use findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55980131/8350143

Comment: For googlers, the url in the warning message is outdated. Here's the actual url: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You need to set the option in the query `useFindAndModify` to `false`, as mentioned in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html).

(search keyword **Currently supported options are**)

> 'useFindAndModify': true by default. Set to false to make
>   findOneAndUpdate() and findOneAndRemove() use native
>   findOneAndUpdate() rather than findAndModify().

and if you see the definition file of mongoose, where mentioned that it calls findAndModify update command.

```
 /**
  * Issues a mongodb findAndModify update command.
  * Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, 
    passing any options,
  * and returns the found document (if any) to the callback. The query 
    executes immediately
  * if callback is passed else a Query object is returned.
  */
 findOneAndUpdate(): DocumentQuery<T | null, T>;
```

Recently updated in the mongoose docs ([Click here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-)) for these deprecation  where mentioned:

> Mongoose's findOneAndUpdate() long pre-dates the MongoDB driver's
>   findOneAndUpdate() function, so it uses the MongoDB driver's
>   findAndModify() function instead.

There are three ways or more by which you can avoid the use of `FindAndModify`:

1. At Global level: Set the option to false.

```
// Make Mongoose use `findOneAndUpdate()`. Note that this option is `true`
// by default, you need to set it to false.
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

2. At connection level: we can configure using the connection options:

```
    mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false });
```

3. At Query level:

```
   await ModelName.findOneAndUpdate({matchQuery},
   {$set: updateData}, {useFindAndModify: false});
```

Comment: why isn't this set by default, I just want to be able to update my documents in peace,

Answer (score 27):

Change the mongoose configuration globally like this:

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Or pass the options in your query string like this:

```
Person.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: body}, {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}).then(..
```

You can also manage the other mongoose deprecation warnings as mention [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I used {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}

Comment: This really worked! - {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}

Answer (score 8):

you also can pass the options at the connection with the requirement option `useNewUrlParser`. Look at the following -> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

```
mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to change your connect method options to get rid of the error:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/DB_Name", {
  keepAlive: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
});
```

You can use it like this.

Answer (score 5):

Mongoose version updates so much that,

for using `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()` it takes an option parameter also see below

```
List.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options, callback) // executes
```

for solving this

Pass this `useFindAndModify: false` in the mongoose.connect in the starting

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDatabase", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true ,useFindAndModify: false });
```

or

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

[clickhere](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) to check related deprecations

Answer (score 2):

```
  mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
  mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
  mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
  mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

These solutions work for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
Mongoose.connect(Config.database,{useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true,useFindAndModify:false});
```

to skip all errors :-)
add this on your index.js or whatever you named it. I mean main js file. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To fix all deprecation warnings, follow the below steps:

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

Replace update() with updateOne(), updateMany(), or replaceOne()
Replace remove() with deleteOne() or deleteMany().
Replace count() with countDocuments(), unless you want to count how many documents are in the whole collection (no filter). In the latter case, use estimatedDocumentCount().

Answer (score 0):

Change mongoose version to 5X (downgrade) in package.json and run npm i to reiantall and then run npm start. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: Recommending downgrading doesn't help the user fix the deprecation, it is just burying the problem. The other answers on this question suggest clear fixes.